# Get post data from Android to PHP

Tags: android, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have a problem to receive post data from Android to [CakePHP](http://CakePHP) 2.3. Below is my code. This function returns values which are in [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) object form.

```
public static JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, JSONObject jObj) {

        // Making HTTP request
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            // Default HTTP Client
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // HTTP POST Header

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jObj.toString());
            httpPost.setEntity(se);
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            // Execute Http Post Request
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    /*
     * To convert the InputStream to String we use the
     * BufferedReader.readLine() method. We iterate until the BufferedReader
     * return null which means there's no more data to read. Each line will
     * appended to a StringBuilder and returned as String.
     */
        String json = "";
        try {
            // Getting Server Response
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            // Reading Server Response
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // Return JSON String
        Log.e("JSON Parser", jObj.toString());
        return jObj;
    }
```

And my CakePHP code is:

```
function addBooksInDb() {
    $this->layout = false;
    $this->autoRender = false;
    debug($this->request);
    debug($_REQUEST['data']);
    debug($_POST);
    die();
}
```

This function will get all post details that comes from an Android POST in my [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) API of CakePHP.

Comment: I suggest to use `okHttp`, Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/32609333/1318946

Comment: it's not helping ,Same error..tanks for help..

Comment: can you post your error?